Check if WhatsApp number is registered without the API
I want to write a program that checks whether the phone number that the user enters is registered in WhatsApp. I can't use the API.
I tried to write the code and this is what I got. However, when you enter a number that is registered in WhatsApp, the console displays that the number is not registered.
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import carrier

def is_whatsapp_number(phone_number):
    try:
        phone_number = phonenumbers.parse(phone_number) 
        if phonenumbers.is_valid_number(phone_number):
            service_provider = carrier.name_for_number(phone_number, lang="EN")
            if "WhatsApp" in service_provider:
                return "YES"
            else:
                return "NO"
        else:
            return "Invalid phone number"
    except phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.NumberParseException:
        return "Invalid phone number"

phone_number = input("Enter the phone number: ")
result = is_whatsapp_number(phone_number)
print(result)


The function carrier.name_for_number cannot verify if a number is associated with WhatsApp. It checks the phone network operator of the number, not whether it is registered on WhatsApp.

how i can check registration in whatsapp? help me please
